# PyFMI package equivalent to linux environment

Tags: python, fmi

Can anyone help me in finding the PyFMI equivalent package for Linux environment. I am using PyFMI-2.2 in windows successfully but the same package I can't use it under Linux environment.
I am getting error as `ImportError: Cannot import PyFMI`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Today PyFMI can easily be installed on both Linux and Windows using conda, see the following post:

[PyFMI in Python 3 environment in Ubuntu 18.04](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59582257/pyfmi-in-python-3-environment-in-ubuntu-18-04)

Answer (score 1):

PyFMI (version 2.3.1) has its own Linux version.

Go to this [PyFMI 2.3.1](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyFMI) link and download the "Source" type PyFMI-2.3.1.zip (md5) file.

Install it by typing this command:
python setup.py install –fmil-home=/path/to/FMI_Library/